# Cannot import modules in IPython

Tags: opencv, installation, ipython, importerror, mathjax

It is my first time to use IPython and I wanted to build a scientific computing environment through a tutorial. Here is the Chinese website that I used : http://hyry.dip.jp/tech/slice/slice.html/24 Not only did it teach how to install IPython but also other modules.I got some problems when I did it : 
1. When I tried to install mathjax using "*from IPython.external.mathjax import install_mathjax; install_mathjax()*". It replies that

```html
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-9209d90709e3> in <module>()
----> 1 from IPython.external.mathjax import install_mathjax
      2 install_mathjax()

ImportError: cannot import name install_mathjax
```

Is it an the environment problem? I have really done my best to try to fix it (and searched). I am newbie to this. Sorry if I am asking stupid question or easy problems. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The tutorial you are using appears to be very old. Why don't you use the current instructions on the official website? http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/install/install.html. Note that especially for beginners, `anaconda` can be very interesting, as it ships the most popular packages for you out of the box.

Comment: I compared the website with the official one and I am sure that I downloaded the newest version. I saw Anaconda after I already installed almost everything... and fixing those problem took me some days...

Comment: I tried to import install_mathjax again today with (command line in official website) and without ipython.
With python, it says "IPython.external.mathjax is deprecated, Mathjax is now installed by default with the notebook package". I have no clue how to do with it...
I am hesitated if I should uninstall everything and install Anaconda instead.
Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Those instructions are for an older version of IPython. You don't need to do that step with the current version.